# How can I convert directory path to full URL

Tags: php, url

I want to convert directory paths to absolute URLs.
For eg.

```
    C:\example\myfile to http://example.com/myfile
```

How can I do this?
Please help me.

Comment: What happens if you want to convert C:\example_two\other_file and C:\example_two isn't specified as Apache's DocumentRoot and therefore isn't accessible trough URL?

Comment: What webserver are you using. Is your document root set to C:\example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** property to get the domain you are running on, then append it to the root of your file location.

i.e. If file is in C:\www\mydir\myfile.file, then

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/mydir/myfile.file';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).